# force user on certain directories rather than the entire share

Tags: samba

Samba's [`force user`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#FORCEUSER) configuration parameter is useful as it allows multiple users to access a share while performing all file operations as a single specified user.

Is it possible however to use the `force user` parameter on a per-directory basis?

I have a number of shares which are accessed by a few different users and on various devices. Recently I created a shared named "OmniShare" which allows access to files in all shares while only having to map a single drive in Windows. I use this on my main computer. It's configured like this:

```
[omnishare]
    path = /home/redacted/OmniShare
    valid users = redacted
    read only = no
    browseable = no
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.20
```

`/home/redacted/OmniShare` is simply a directory containing symbolic links to the specified `path` for the other shares. Since some shares are accessed by users other than `redacted`, I have refrained from writing through the OmniShare to prevent others having issues reading and modifying files.

Is it possible to use the `force user` parameter so that file operations are performed by a specified user based on the symbolically linked directory?

---

Example:

File operations in `/home/redacted/OmniShare/user1` are performed by `user1` rather than `redacted`.

File operations in `/home/redacted/OmniShare/user2` are performed by `user2` rather than `redacted`.

Or, perhaps, there's a better way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `OmniShare` is acting a little bit like Microsoft's [Distributed Filesystem Namespaces](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(v=ws.10).aspx) in function, though not in implementation.  DFS Namespaces allows you to present disparate shares as a single unified share.

I think you'd do well to have a look at: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DFS

Samba can "knit" together shares much like DFS Namespaces. Rater than using symbolic links to filesystem locations you'll use symbolic links to SMB shares. I would expect the `force user` functionality of the destination share to be observed by Samba (and I wouldn't set any `force user` on the DFS root).

Comment: Thanks. Having read the pages you've linked and some more pages in Samba's documentation, this seems to be exactly what I'm after.